# ListId Error when send an email using Exact Target soap API

Tags: email, api, soap, marketing-cloud

I am using Soap API to send email,if my List id is wrong it create a new List,so it is making a huge number of unwanted lists,Idealy the call must return with error .iam now doing a retreive to check the list id is valid and send mail ,it is time consuming so any idea to solve this issue?

Email send Object as below

```
    Send sendobj = new Send()
    {
        FromName = "nikhil",
        FromAddress = "nikhil@gmail.com",

        Email = new Email()
        {
            HTMLBody = "Body",
            TextBody = "text",
            Subject = "subject",
            Name = "name"
        },

        // Setting SubscriberList 
        List = new List[1]
        {
            new List
            {
                ID = 50, 
                IDSpecified = true 
            }
        }
    };


 string cRequestID = string.Empty;
 string cStatus = string.Empty;
 CreateResult[] cResults = client.Create(new CreateOptions(), new APIObject[] { sendobj }, out cRequestID, out cStatus); // Send Message
```

if the value 50 as List id is an invalid id then it will create a fake list in exact target account,is that correct?

Comment: am i doing wrong? or question is not clear?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking - do you want to know about new lists, or how to call by list ID?

Comment: i have an issue that if a user want to send email to subscriber list and if they enter a invalid listid then the api call get success status,that is my problem

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm not recognizing what language this is - is this an SDK?  Is there a code sample you based this off of? I don't recognize this at all.

Comment: this is my reference http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_email_send_definition/

Comment: Your code sample above is so far off - I don't even know how to help you.What language are you developing in? Have you gotten anything to actually work?

Comment: i am working with c# , its the most optimised code for send objected,all my code is working and the problem is the way of behaving service

Comment: The title of the question and what you are doing are two different things.  A sendobj is not a send definition.  That may be causing issues.

Comment: Please be sure to mark the question answered if you are getting things working, that way everyone can benefit.  If it's not solved, let me know so we can get it working.

Comment: still it create new list when the list id is wrong

Answer (score 1):

A simple SOAP packet for sending to a list -

```
<soap:Body>
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Options/>
        <Objects xsi:type="Send">
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <Email>
                <ID>12345</ID>
            </Email>
            <List>
                <ID>12345</ID>
            </List>
        </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

This SOAP body will send to an email to a listID.

The list ID needs to be in your account, or the call should fail.  Not exactly sure what success you are getting, or what is meant by a new list being created. This would allow you to then send directly to a list, and would be good for sending occasionally.

If you wish to create an EmailSendDefintion, you would base your code off the sample you are already looking at. The code you have above doesn't appear to be doing any of that sample.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?